# Systemd, failed to start dcos-link-env.service

Tags: server, systemd

The following are details of `systemctl status dcos-link-env.service`

```
 ● dcos-link-env.service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dcos-link-env.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-09-27 16:40:42 MYT; 54min ago
      Process: 7021 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/profile.d (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

    Sep 27 16:40:42 slave1 systemd[1]: Starting dcos-link-env.service...
    Sep 27 16:40:42 slave1 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
    Sep 27 16:40:42 slave1 systemd[1]: Failed to start dcos-link-env.service.
    Sep 27 16:40:42 slave1 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Sep 27 16:40:42 slave1 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Warning: dcos-link-env.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

UPDATE 1:
I followed the solution provided by "Mark Stosberg" and it able to solve the problem the line he referring to. However there is a new error appear which is kind of vague(at least to me).Below is the error.

```
systemctl status dcos-link-env
● dcos-link-env.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dcos-link-env.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-09-29 17:08:16 MYT; 2min 43s ago
 Main PID: 7814 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 29 17:08:16 agenttest3 systemd[1]: Starting dcos-link-env.service...
Sep 29 17:08:16 agenttest3 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 29 17:08:16 agenttest3 systemd[1]: Failed to start dcos-link-env.service.
Sep 29 17:08:16 agenttest3 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 29 17:08:16 agenttest3 systemd[1]: dcos-link-env.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
>  ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/profile.d (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

So this command is exiting with a failure code. Have you it run on the CLI as root to confirm it works as expected?

On Ubuntu 16.04, `which mkdir` shows that it this binary is located at `/bin/mkdir`, not `/usr/bin/mkdir` as you have.

Comment: It's seem the agent node can't start any service, probably because I might messed up something when I was upgrading my node from 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: Your comment doesn't seem to responding to my answer. Did you try fixing the path to mkdir?

Comment: I did a fresh install on all of my testing node and currently testing other thing my employer asked me to do. I will try to respond to you after I tries your answer when I need to start on working on dcos again. I'm on my intern and am sorry for this as I'm still new and not yet good at networking stuff(ubuntu). Thanks for taking your times to read my post and provide guidance.

Comment: I change the mkdir directory and the error for the line you referring to is gone but when I check the status again another error appear(SEE UPDATE 1) again :| . But thanks for your guidance at least I'm getting somewhere now

Comment: Since the main process failed, you should look at any logs, and post the `ExecStart=` line you used as well as the `Type=` directive.  Check that your [Type=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) directive matches the kind of process you have.

Comment: It seem the problems lies with exectstartpre and exect start, however I solve the problem by copy /bin/mkdir to /usr/bin/ which may not be an "correct solution"(i guess?), this service was actually called and required by a process when I was installing dcos process so even if i changes the path of exec to /bin/mkdir, whenever I run the dcos installation command the path is automatically revert to /usr/bin/mkdir. This solve the error for now. But I will look into it whenever I have free time or which line that actually revert the path back to default